# Lists of deprecated enums in Modern Opengl?

Tags: opengl, enums, deprecated

As I write `OpenGL` program using `Opengl version 4.0 core profile`, I find the `GL_QUADS` is deprecated. I have find a question and answer in deprecated functions, but where can I find a lists of deprecated enums in OpenGL 4.0?

Comment: is it really needed? if you want do draw something using glDrawArrays then if you look at the docs http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml you will notice thet GL_QUADS is missing... and you will get glError

Comment: `GL_QUADS` is [***removed***, not deprecated](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Deprecation) in 4.0 core. "Deprecated" means that it still exists and can be used, but may be removed at some future date. "Removed" means... removed. Not available.

Comment: BTW, if you're looking for loading libraries that provide "clean" GL 3.x+ headers, [there are some available.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) GL3w and the SDK's library both provide headers that only contain core material (and extensions, of course)

Comment: @fen I searched and the `GL_QUADS` are still alive on some pages e.g. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml, and not noticed it is removed in OpenGL 4.0. thank you for your information. I will use OpenGL4.0 reference pages then.

Comment: @NicolBolas I use QGLWidget in Qt, which can also provide a clean core profile of OpenGL4.0 by using QGLFormat class.

Comment: @tlh1987: I was talking about the headers themselves, not the context. So that you don't have enums like `GL_QUADS` around; that way, you get a compiler error when you try to use them.

Comment: @NicolBolas good headers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On *[www.opengl.org/registry](http://www.opengl.org/registry/)* you can find *[enumext.spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/enumext.spec)* file, that a text file containing the list of OpenGL enumerant symbols.

The enumerants marked in the categories VERSION__DEPRECATED (i.e. VERSION_1_1_DEPRECATED enum:)
 you can find that list.